# Open CSV file and replace content if is empty

Tags: php, csv, awk, sed

I am running somo Mysqli querys that generates me CSV output files. Some of them are just empty CSV files because nothing matches with the query parameters. I want a script that opens and replaces the content (only if the file is empty) of all CSV files in a folder.

It can be in PHP but also awk, sed or similars.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Is empty file really empty as in it doesn't even have a header? 2. What is the empty content to be replaced with? 3. What did you do to try and solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, file is really empty and i want to replace with "./.", i tryed doing `mysqli_num_rows` and if the return is 0 make a file with `fopen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash:

```
file=foo; if [ -w "$file" -a ! -s "$file" ] ; then echo "./." > "$file" ; fi
```

If file `foo` exist (`-w`) and (`-a`) is a zero-length file (`! -s`) write `./.` over its empty contents. You can test it by `touch foo` and then running that script.

Comment: Working removing the last comma in the command:  `file=foo; if [ -w "$file" -a ! -s "$file" ] ; then echo "./." > "$file" ; fi `  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, there was some runaway quote, just noticed and removed.

Comment: Just one more question, how can i do this for all the csv files in the folder, trying something like this: `file= *.csv;`

Comment: `for file in *.csv ; do if [ -w "$file" -a ! -s "$file" ] ; then echo "./." > "$file" ; fi ; done` and you can loose the `file=foo` part in that case.